# Center a overlaid text on background image

Tags: html, css

I want the text (`.herotext`) to be perfectly in the center vertically and horizontally of the background image (`.herobanner`). This text is meant to overlay the image just like with a slider/carousel.

I have attempted to do this with the `margin: 0 auto` but without any results

CSS

```
.herobanner {
    height:500px;
    width:100%;background:#000;
    background-size:cover !important;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background: url(../img/head.jpg) center
}

.herotext {
    color:#fff;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="herobanner">
    <h1 class="herotext">Hello</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Does text-align:center on .herobanner not work?

Comment: It does, however I also need the vertical padding.

Comment: I'm not the expert but: .herobanner needs display:table-cell; and vertical-align:middle

Comment: Sry i was wrong: .herobanner -> display:table; .herotext ->display:table-cell; and vertical-align:middle;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution

```css
.herobanner {
  height: 500px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #000;
  background-size: cover !important;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background: url(../img/head.jpg) center;
  background: lightblue;
  display: table;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}
.herotext {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="herobanner">
  <h1 class="herotext">Hello</h1>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You always need a wrapper div to vertically position, until CSS gets it's shit together and allows for vertical-alignment in non-table situations.

Plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/aaTGmjwYlH5nZzgW4IJL

```
    <div class="herobanner">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <h1 class="herotext">Hello</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
```